# Python 3, how to import modules for pip installable package and runnable script?

Tags: python-3.x, console-application, python-import, python-packaging, module-packaging

I wrote a Python 3 console-application which has the same structure as the example below. I want to know how I should be importing the modules in order to achieve the behavior specified in the desired functionality section.

```
/foo
  |-/foo
  |   |-__init__.py
  |   |-/bar
  |   |   |-__init__.py
  |   |   |-eggs.py
  |   |-ham.py
  |   |-spam.py
  |-setup.py
```

Where:

1. The `spam` module has the `main` function
2. The `spam` module imports the Ham class in the `ham` module
3. The `ham` module imports the Egg class in the `eggs` module
4. Both `__init__.py` files are empty
5. Basic `setup.py` file that imports `setuptools`

**Desired Functionality**

- I want to be able to upload the console app to [PyPi](https://pypi.org/). Then it can be downloaded as a package with `pip`, and be executed in the terminal.

  ```
  ~/>> foo
  ```
- I also want to be able to run it as a Python script.

  ```
  ~/foo>> python3 foo/spam.py
  ```

I found, what I think is a hacky, way to achieve this.

**The (hacky) Solution**

In order to get the installed package and Python script functionality, I added a `try: ... except: ...` which works but it doesn't seem the right way to do this.

```
try:
    from module import Class # import will work for running as script
except:
    # relative import will work for running as a package installed with pip
    from .module import Class
```

If I only leave the relative import, and try to run the code as a Python script, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo/spam.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .ham import Ham
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.ham'; '__main__' is not a package
```

A similar situation occurs if I leave the regular import and run console application:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../foo/spam.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ham import Ham
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ham'
```

**The Files**

`__init__.py` files are empty

`spam.py`

```
"""spam module"""

try:
    from ham import Ham
except:
    from .ham import Ham

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__:
    main()
```

`ham.py`

```
"""ham module"""

try:
    from eggs import Egg
except:
    from .eggs import Egg

class Ham:
    pass
```

`eggs.py`

```
"""eggs module"""

class Egg:
    pass
```

`setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="foo",
    version="1.0.0",
    author="Pablo",
    description="Example",
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": ["foo=foo.spam:main"]
    },
)
```